# Laravel - Loading multiple related models

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application I have three models `User`, `Deal` and `DealFile`

A `User` can have many `Deal`

A `Deal` can have many `DealFile`

I have a job that sends emails once a day to users who have deals that have had files added that day.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Models\DealFile;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;
use App\Notifications\DealFileUploadedNotification;

class SendFilesUploadedNotifications implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $files = DealFile::where('email_sent', false)->get();
        
        $owner_files = [];

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (!isset($owner_files[$file->deal->owner->email])) {
                $owner_files[$file->deal->owner->email] = [];
            }

            array_push($owner_files[$file->deal->owner->email], $file);
        }

        foreach ($owner_files as $email => $files) {
            Notification::route('mail', $email)->notify(new DealFileUploadedNotification($files));
        }
    }
}
```

This creates an array like so:

```
'john.smith@newable.co.uk' => [
    // A collection instance containing many DealFile
];
```

Is there an efficient way to load related models from user so that I can do the following in an email?

```
User
--Deal
----DealFile
----DealFile
----DealFile
--Deal
```

I was thinking something like so

```
$users = User::with('deals')->whereHas('deals', function ($query) {
    $query->whereHas('files', function($innerQuery){
        $innerQuery->where('email_sent', 0);
    });
})->get();
```

However, the related DealFile objects returned are just all of them, ignoring my WHERE clause.

---

I may have over complicated as this is essentially what I was after

```
$users = User::select('hubspot_id', 'name', 'email')
    ->has('deals')
    ->with(['deals.files' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('email_sent', 0);
    }])->get();
```

Comment: Yes, I'm just about to update my question. :)

Comment: try   $users = User::with(['deals','deals.files'=>function($innerQuery){
            $innerQuery->where('email_sent', 0);
        }])->whereHas('deals.files', function($innerQuery){
            $innerQuery->where('email_sent', 0);
        })->get();

Comment: Is there any drawbacks to how I've done this? As its exactly what I was after.

Comment: try and see if you get exact output .i dont find any draw back if it working